# jquery getting child divs and splicing them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have markup like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
     <div class="left">1</div>
     <div class="right">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <div class="left">1</div>
     <div class="right">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <div class="left">1</div>
     <div class="right">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <div class="left">1</div>
     <div class="right">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <div class="left">1</div>
     <div class="right">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <div class="left">1</div>
     <div class="right">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the children of `container` so all of the items, then I want to `.slice(0,2)` so I can get the first two `item` divs.

I've tried using `$('.container').children()`, but this only seems to return the first item.  Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, this is what you're after:

```
var $firstTwo = $('.container > .item:lt(2)');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9jp5D/

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like

```
var first2divs = $('.container .item').slice(0, 2);
```

Comment: If the `.item` elements are what you are after then you should definitely use a selector that selects them. Then you can iterate over the elements that jQuery returns however you'd like.